# Squid + windows active directory Authentication + Dansguardian

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, squid, dansguardian

I have to configure squid authentication + dansguardian web filtering on ubuntu server. Can anyone please tell me how to do it.

I can configure squid transparent mode & dansguardian. But I do not know how to configure squid authentication and making users to get authenticated to browse.

The authentication is to be done with microsoft windows active directory. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated squid with Active Directory using this link : [Configuring Squid on Linux to authenticate with Active Directory | PaperCut KB](http://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/ConfiguringSquidProxyToAuthenticateWithActiveDirectory)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you're authenticating against.  For example, I once got squid to authenticate against a Mac OS X Open Directory server (effectively LDAP).

A few tips to get you started:

- Transparent proxying and authenticated proxying are mutually exclusive.  You can have either one, but not both.
- Look for squid.conf on your Ubuntu server.  That is what you'll have to edit in order to make the authentication lookups against your LDAP (or NTLM or ...) server.
- Figure out how to get your proxy's IP (or FQDN) and port into your workstations.  If there are very few, you can manually configure them.  Windows and Mac OS X can be configured with Group Policies and Workgroup Manager (a.k.a. MCX).
- Once Squid has authentication, it will pass that through DansGuardian.  No additional configuration in DansGuardian should be necessary.
- Check this web page for lots of details:  http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for "transparent proxying and authenticated proxying are mutually exclusive".

Answer (score 0):

The following how to shows Squid + Kerberos with AD + web filtering done by qlproxy.

http://www.howtoforge.com/web-filtering-on-squid-3-with-quintolabs-content-security-1.4-and-windows-active-directory-integration-p2

Comment: Are you affiliated with qlproxy? You gave 5 answer in a row referring to this product

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.